# jquery animate with percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a very simple animation, just like this:

```
$("article").animate({
    left:"-=70"
},1000)
```

this works, it substracts 70px from the current "left" value.
but the problem is, I need that to be a percentage:

```
$("article").animate({
    left:"-=70%"
},1000)
```

Of course, this doesn't work. Any work around?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsU37/

Comment: what about computing the value required using the width ?

Comment: You can calculate roughly how many pixels 70% is based perhaps on the width of its parent element, but I'm unsure of exactly what you want 70% of.  It's current position?  The width of its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've tried the above and does not work, you can try calculating the actual value :

```
$("article").animate({
  left: parseInt($(this).css('left'),10)*0.3
},1000)
```

Explaining : `$(this).css('left')` should get the current value, similar to `125px`, which is passed through `parseInt` to remove the `px` part, and multiplied by 0.3 to get 30% of it (assume it's what you mean by -70%)

**Edit:** See fiddle that works here http://jsfiddle.net/demaf/ . Do note:

- since I'm using a click handler, I can no longer use `this`, so I've changed to `$('article')`.
- element to be animated needs to have an initial value for left that is non-zero (otherwise math would give a 0 value and no animation occurs)
- element needs to use the `left` value, hence needs to be `position`ed accordingly

Comment: looks good, but it crashes, check the jsfiddle I've setup.
And,  "left" right now is 0, doing "left: -70%" moves it to the left, while "left:30%" moves it to the right. but that's not important, of course.

Comment: expanded with example. For this method to work `left` needs to initially have an explicit non-zero value.